# objective-c exceptions not caught in swift 3 do catch handler

Tags: try-catch, swift3, throw, nsexception

I use a objective-c library in my swift code base.  The library may throw an exception.  Unfortunately, the exception does not get caught within Swift 3.  How do I work around this issue?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

In general it is no good idea to use Objective-C exception handling, but sometimes it's neccessary. ;)

Swift exception handling is totally different from Objective-C. You can't catch Objective-C exceptions in Swift directly. Instead, you should write an Objective-C wrapper, e. g.:

```
@implementation NSDictionary(NoException)

- (id)noExceptionValueForKey:(NSString *)inKey {
    @try {
        return [self valueForKey:inKey];
    }
    @catch(NSException *anException) {
        // More exception handling if neccessary
        return nil;
    }
}

@end
```

From Swift you should call `noExceptionValueForKey:` instead of `valueForKey:`.

Comment: So does this mean that it is actually impossible, at this point in time, to write a pure Swift application for iOS?

Comment: @Jules: Unfortunately yes, for some rare problems you need Objective C. Catching Objective C exceptions is one of it.